# How to print traceback message to new line in python

Tags: python, html

I am using html email and .format() for string to pass in the arguments

Below are my python code :

```
import sys

try:
    print(5 / 0)
except Exception as e:
    send_error_email(exp_message=format_exc())
```

and then fetching the function send_error_email and pass to MIMEMultipart mail script

```
 html = """
            <html>
              <body>
    
                <b> Exception Details: </b> {exp_message}
    
              </body>
            </html>
            """.format(exp_message=exp_message)
```

**Getting Output in one line in mail** :

> Exception Data : Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Build\test\workfile\python-practice\exception_test.py", line 54, in get_details print(100/0) ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

**Expected Output should be every message in new line**:

> Exception Data : Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Build\test\workfile\python-practice\exception_test.py", line 54,
> in get_details print(100/0)
> ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Comment: @enzo Do you mean 
send_error_email(exp_message='<br />'.join(format_exc().splitlines()))

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a question being asked here at all; but if there is, it seems to be about *what the output HTML data should be*.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, you can use a line break `<br>` to put the exception on another line. Also, you can change up your formatting just a bit. Since there's only one argument in the formatter, you can just use positional arguments and not keyword arguments.

```html
 html = """
            <html>
              <body>
                <b> Exception Data: </b>
                <br>
                {}
              </body>
            </html>
            """.format(exp_message)
```

Comment: I tried still all trackeback messege is printing in one line only , I need to make every data to new line

Answer (score 0):

For Better and Pretty Printing of Exceptions, Refer the [Python's Traceback Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html)
Specifically, check the traceback.format_* methods (eg. format_exception())

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the Python's newline with the HTML's line break.

```py
html_exp_message = exp_message.replace('\n', '<br>')

html = """
            <html>
              <body>
                <b> Exception Details: </b> {}
              </body>
            </html>
            """.format(html_exp_message)
```